# My laptop shuts down on hdmi during video games and 60fps videos

Tags: laptop, hdmi

First of all, sorry for my English here is my problem:
I have an old Asus laptop and i don't have a battery. My laptop is 8 years old, i'm using this computer with a monitor with HDMI connection, whenever i try to play a game or do anything that will force the ram my computer shuts down, this problem does not occur without the HDMI connection, is this happening because i don't have a battery? I googled this issue and tried few solutions but they don't work. 
Please help me.

Comment: Could be a thermal problem. Is the resolution of the TV bigger than the one of your built-in monitor (GPU needs to compute more pixels). The GPU (or CPU or something else) may overheat and the system performs an emergency shut off.

Comment: Yes TV resolution is 1920x1080 and computers is 1368x768.

Comment: Use a tool like [GPU-Z](https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-gpu-z/) to monitor the GPU temperature (see "Sensors" tab) and compare the situation with and without TV attached.

Comment: thank you, i will try that

Comment: GPU temperature with TV goes around 93-95 °C  and without TV it's around 90°C

Comment: @VelihanKömürcü Anything above 95C is potentially dangerous, and will usually trigger a thermal shut off. Most likely your system needs the dust cleaned out of it and/or the thermal conductive material (thermal paste usually) replaced. It could also be that your ambient room temperature is too high or your system was just poorly designed, or some combination of the above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, i will make sure that my laptop gets checked out.